# Elasticsearch find all messages that were 'delivered' but not 'opened'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following elasticsearch index data:

```
id|message_id|   action|
 1|         1|delivered|
 2|         1|   opened|
 3|         2|delivered|
 4|         3|delivered|
 5|         4|delivered|
 6|         5|   opened|
```

How to find all 'not opened' messages?
Expected result:

```
id|message_id|   action|
 3|         2|delivered|
 4|         3|delivered|
```

Comment: something along `* AND NOT action:opened` should do (even if `action:delivered` sounds more obvious for your exemple) [Lucene query syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators)

Comment: Would a terms query work here? Do you have the JSON of one of these documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to be difficult with a single query because your data is normalized and thus would require a join on itself which AFAIK is not really possible in ES. I think there are two solutions:

1. De-normalize your data using a nested field for **action**.
2. Use two queries: In the first query you retrieve all messages that were **delivered**. For the second query you use the **message_ids** from the first query and use a bool filter to combine an `ids filter` and a `term filter` to get the ones not opened.

Answer (score 0):

use the *not* filter.  Here is an example:

```
GET index1/type1/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "not": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "action": {
                "value": "opened"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You will get all message_ids then. I want to exclude message_id if it has 'opened' action from result